# Using a 2-d Array to Make a graph

Tags: c++

I am trying to plot a few points on the graph but I am not sure how to do it. Basically my goal is to plot the pints using a 2-d array.

Here is what the graph should look like:

```
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
   1                              
   2                          C   
   3        F                     
   4     F  M  F                  
   5        F                     
   6                              
   7                    X         
   8                              
   9                 B  B  B      
  10                       C
```

Here are the points to the graph (input file):

```
Rows    10
Cols    10

M   4,3
C   2,9
X   7,7
B   9,6
B   9,7
B   9,8
C   10,8
F   3,3
F   5,3
F   4,2
F   4,4
```

I have tried using if statements so if it encounters a letter in the input file it would automatically record it into the file. Can you please give me ideas on how to do this. I am not asking you guys to write all of the code. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the specific question? As-is it is unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The points that are given is a .txt file. The Rows and Cols shows the size of the grid. And letters like "M" is what needs to be plotted on that grid. The point for "M" is 4,3 (x,y). So it needs to appear as it is in the graph shown. So my question is, with the given points, make a grid that plots the all the points as shown. How would I do that?

Comment: Write the program and come back if you have any problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could sort out the parsing of the file data yourself (or perhaps better make separate ticket). As for printing the data out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Graph
{

private:

    std::vector<char> _graph;
    size_t _rows;
    size_t _cols;
    char _ch;

public:

    Graph(size_t rows, size_t cols, char ch = '.') : _rows(rows), _cols(cols), _ch(ch) { _graph.assign((_rows + 1) * (_cols + 1), _ch); }

    bool PutChar(char c, size_t row, size_t col)
    {
        if (row > _rows || col > _cols || row == 0 || col == 0)
            return false;

        _graph[col + row * _rows] = c;
        return true;
    }

    char GetChar(size_t row, size_t col)
    {
        if (row > _rows || col > _cols || row == 0 || col == 0)
            return _ch;

        return _graph[col + row * _rows];
    }

    void PrintGraph()
    {
        printf("%3c", 0x20);

        for (size_t col = 1; col <= _cols; ++col)
            printf("%3zu", col);

        printf("\n");

        for (size_t row = 1; row <= _rows; ++row)
        {
            printf("%3zu", row);

            for (size_t col = 1; col <= _cols; ++col)
            {
                printf("%3c", GetChar(row, col));
            }

            printf("\n");
        }
    }
};

int main()
{

    Graph graph(10, 10);

    graph.PutChar('M', 4, 3);
    graph.PutChar('C', 2, 9);
    graph.PutChar('X', 7, 7);
    graph.PutChar('B', 9, 6);
    graph.PutChar('B', 9, 7);
    graph.PutChar('B', 9, 8);
    graph.PutChar('C', 10, 8);
    graph.PutChar('F', 3, 3);
    graph.PutChar('F', 5, 3);
    graph.PutChar('F', 4, 2);
    graph.PutChar('F', 4, 4);

    graph.PrintGraph();

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

[image]

What I find odd in your task that the X is Y and Y is X and that both start with 1. This makes it awkward, not sure why it needs to be like this.

EDIT: Just realised that the above doesn't quite use 2d array as requested, but emulates it.

Answer (score 2):

> Basically my goal is to plot the points using a 2-d array.

- The first thing you need to do is to extract the data from your text file
- For each line of data, split them into: `symbol`, `x`, `y`

  ```
  e.g: 'M', 4, 3  corresponds to (symbol, x, y)
  ```
- Update your 2D array according to the extracted data
- `matrix[x][y] = symbol;`

<sub>You can of course offset `x` and `y` by 1 since your array begins with index 0.</sub>